# Nuevo tipo de datos en Python

Tags: python-3.x, estructuras-de-datos

Primero perdonad si hay alguna incorrección, soy nuevo tanto aquí como desarrollando en Python.

Estaba haciendo, para aprender, una árbol, por mi cuenta ya me he creado un tipo de datos (Nodo) con una nueva clase. Contiene un string, más una lista de nodos. El problema que tengo es que cuando quiere añadir un nodo a lista den no dos me da el siguiente error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\Aplicaciones\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1438, in _exec
        pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
      File "E:\Aplicaciones\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
        exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
      File "E:/Users/miguel/PycharmProjects/Ejercicios/FindStrings.py", line 163, in <module>
        result = findStrings4(w_redux, queries)
      File "E:/Users/miguel/PycharmProjects/Ejercicios/FindStrings.py", line 120, in findStrings4
        arbol = arbol + primer_nodo
      File "E:/Users/miguel/PycharmProjects/Ejercicios/FindStrings.py", line 101, in __add__
        (self.hijos).extend(other)
    AttributeError: 'Nodo' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

No lo entiendo porque si veo el tipo de la lista de nodos me dice que List.
Lo que he creado es lo siguiente:

```
class Nodo:
    def __init__(self, cadena=None, hijos=[]):
        self.cadena = cadena
        self.hijos = hijos

    def __add__(self, other):
        if (len(self.hijos)) == 0:
            (self.hijos).extend(other)
        else:
            for i in range(len(self.hijos)):
                if self.hijos[i].cadena > other.cadena:
                    self.hijos.insert(i - 1, other.cadena)
        return self

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.hijos)
 

def findStrings4(w, queries):
    arbol = Nodo('c')
    primer_nodo = Nodo('a')
    segundo_nodo =Nodo('b')
    arbol.hijos = primer_nodo

    arbol.cadena = "Hola Mundo"
    print(arbol.cadena)
    arbol = arbol + primer_nodo
    # print(arbol.hijos)
    arbol = arbol + segundo_nodo
    print(arbol.hijos)
```

Está claro que estoy haciendo algo mal, pero por mucho que leo, no sé que puede ser.

¿Alguna idea de donde la puedo estar liando?

Un saludo

Comment: Hola, m4519ec. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu pregunta y mostrar el código donde instancias el objeto y llamas a los métodos? De esta forma podemos ver exactamente el recorrido que hace (aunque lo normal es que instancies Nodo y luego llames al método __add__ queremos asegurarnos de que parámetros pasas).

Comment: Falta mucho código relevante, no se ve donde defines el atributo `hijos`. Deberías de añadirlo. Saludos

Comment: Aparte del error que mencionas, veo unos cuantos problemas potenciales más. En cualquier caso, para explicártelos bien y darte soluciones sería necesario que pusieras el código completo, no solo de la clase `Nodo`, sino también de la parte que hace uso de esa clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo claro cuál es el objetivo del código, por lo que es posible que tenga más errores de los que he detectado de momento.

El error que causa la excepción que has visto, está causado por la línea:

```
arbol.hijos = primer_nodo
```

ya que estás asignando a `hijos` un objeto de tipo `Nodo`, cuando se supone que `hijos` debería ser una lista. Por eso, luego no te funcionan las operaciones de listas que intentas sobre `arbol.hijos`. Por ejemplo, `len(self.hijos)` ya no es la longitud de una lista, sino de un `Nodo` y ese nodo tiene longitud 0 porque no tiene hijos. Por tanto el primer `if` se cumple y se intenta un `self.hijos.extend()` que falla porque `hijos` no es una lista.

Este error se arreglaría haciendo:

```
arbol = Nodo('c')
arbol.hijos = [primer_nodo]
```

para asegurarse de que es una lista y no un nodo a secas. O también con `arbol.hijos.append(primer_nodo)`. O tamibén, ¿por qué no? pasándolo como parámetro al constructor cuando creas el árbol:

```
arbol = Nodo('c', [primer_nodo])
```

O mejor aún, haciendo uso de la "interfaz" que has programado, según la cual se añaden hijos con la operación `+` (si funcionara bien, que tiene otros errores como veremos):

```
arbol = Nodo('c')
arbol = arbol + primer_nodo
```

Por otro lado, no se entiende del todo qué pretendes hacer en la operación `+`. Parece que quieres meter al hijo en una posición tal que la lista de hijos simpre esté ordenada alfabéticamente, por su cadena. Pero en cambio, si no encuentras ningún hijo alfabéticamente mayor que el que estás insertando, al final no se mete en ningún lugar (cuando supongo que lo que querrías sería insertarlo al final en este caso). También tendrías que hacer un `break` una vez lo hayas insertado, para evitar insertarlo varias veces.

Además, aquí: `self.hijos.insert(i - 1, other.cadena)` no estás metiendo otro nodo en la lista de hijos, sino la cadena. Es decir ¿qué quieres tener como lista de hijos? Entiendo que quieres una lista de objetos de tipo `Nodo`, pero en cambio `other.cadena` sería de tipo `str`.

Y una cosa más, en el caso de que no hubiera previamente ningún hijo en la lista, estás intentando `(self.hijos).extend(other)`, lo cual ya vimos que daba un problema cuando `self.hijos` no era una lista, pero es que te dará problemas igualmente si lo es, porque `extend()` espera como argumento otra lista, y le estás pasando solo un nodo. Debes usar `.append()` en vez de `.extend()` para agregar un solo elemento.

Estos problemas se arreglan por ejemplo así:

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        if (len(self.hijos)) == 0:
            (self.hijos).append(other)
        else:
            insertado = False
            for i in range(len(self.hijos)):
                if self.hijos[i].cadena > other.cadena:
                    self.hijos.insert(i - 1, other)
                    insertado = True
                    break
            if not insertado:
                self.hijos.append(other)
        return self
```

Este código puede simplificarse mucho y hacers más pythónico, pues realmente no hace falta verificar si la lista está vacía ya que si lo estuviera se hará igualmente el `.append()` final. En vez de iterar por los índices, se puede usar `enumerate()` para iterar a la vez por índices y elementos. Y finalmente se puede hacer uso de la cláusula `for/else` para ejecutar el `.append()` final si no se ha insertado, sin necesidad del booleano `insertado`:

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        for i, hijo in enumerate(self.hijos):
            if hijo.cadena > other.cadena:
                self.hijos.insert(i - 1, other)
                break
        else:
            self.hijos.append(other)
        return self
```

Otra posible fuente de problemas es asignar como valor por defecto a un parámetro una lista vacía, como hiciste en el constructor. Es mejor usar como valor por defecto `None` y desde el código detectar ese caso para crear la lista vacía, así:

```
    def __init__(self, cadena=None, hijos=None):
        self.cadena = cadena
        if hijos is None:
            hijos = []
        self.hijos = hijos
```

de este modo la lista vacía se crea dentro de la función y no "fuera" y te aseguras de que es una lista diferente cada vez que llamas al constructor.

Para terminar, yo implementaría también un método `__repr__()` para mostrar lo que hay en un Nodo de una forma "amigable", lo que te será útil para depurar y para cuando quieras imprimir lo que hay en la lista `arbol.hijos` al final. Por ejemplo, una representación "amigable" podría ser algo como `Nodo("a", [2 hijos])` que resume que es un objeto de tipo `Nodo`, que su cadena es `"a"` y que en su lista `hijos` tiene dos elementos.  Puedes lograr esta representación añadiendo este método:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Nodo({!r}, [{} hijos])".format(self.cadena, len(self.hijos))
```

## Código final

Juntando todo lo anterior, éste sería un ejemplo de código final:

```
class Nodo:
    def __init__(self, cadena=None, hijos=None):
        self.cadena = cadena
        if hijos is None:
            hijos = []
        self.hijos = hijos

    def __add__(self, other):
        for i, hijo in enumerate(self.hijos):
            if hijo.cadena > other.cadena:
                self.hijos.insert(i - 1, other)
                break
        else:
            self.hijos.append(other)
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Nodo({!r}, [{} hijos])".format(self.cadena, len(self.hijos))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.hijos)
 

arbol = Nodo('Padre')
primer_nodo = Nodo('b')
segundo_nodo =Nodo('a')
tercer_nodo =Nodo('c')

arbol = arbol + primer_nodo
arbol = arbol + segundo_nodo
arbol = arbol + tercer_nodo
print(arbol)
print(arbol.hijos)
```

Si lo ejecutas, el resultado que sale en pantalla es:

```
Nodo('Padre', [3 hijos])
[Nodo('a', [0 hijos]), Nodo('b', [0 hijos]), Nodo('c', [0 hijos])]
```

que espero que sea lo que pretendías (ya te digo que no tengo del todo claro qué funcionalidad pretendes implementar)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha sido realmente didáctico. siento que la cagada sea tan trivial, pero me ha servido para aprender unas cuantas cosas.